How to register a new ServerRestHandler?
I'd like to add support for Scala Futures in my Quarkus app, e.g.
I want to have a endpoint like this:
    @GET
    @Path("/greet/future")
    @Produces(Array(TEXT_PLAIN))
    def futureGreeting(): Future[String] =
       Future.successful("Hello from the future")
    end futureGreeting

I found org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.CompletionStageResponseHandler and implemented a corresponding ResponseHandler for Scala Futures.
I tried to register the ServerRestHandler using the Java SPI mechanism by creating a
META-INF/services/org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.spi.ServerRestHandler file and referencing my class.
However, it looks like this is not the way how things are registered in Quarkus.
How can I register my ServerRestHandler so that it is used?
I debugged more into this and found that the CompletionStageResponseHandler seems to be registered by
AsyncReturnTypeScanner .. however, I couldn't figure out how to make/register my own MethodScanner :-/
Any help highly appreciated!

This can only be done via an extension. I would suggest checking the quarkus-rest-kotlin-deployment and more specifically here,
